# Anyone knows a way around creating a html character code for Time?

Tags: html

Does anyone know a way around creating a html character code for Time? or a way of manipulating any other character code to create one that looks like time. Or a font with symbols that can be used for time.

Comment: What do you mean by time? a clock?

Comment: Well yes. Just curious if its possible.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Did you downvote me? Just asking if its possible. Saw a way around doing that for location and was thinking if there is also a way around that for time.

Comment: Nope, probably a drive by down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use font awesome for a clock, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sxh0n7d1/44/

`<i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i>`

http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

Or you can use the html code for a watch `&#x231a;`- ⌚ I dont think it looks as nice though.

Comment: Wow. That is cool. I am also checking out the link to the fontawesome you gave. Very good discovery. There is a whole bunch of other stuff one can do with that.Thanks a lot.

Comment: the clock looks better. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

you can use an online tool like this one: http://www.pentacom.jp/pentacom/bitfontmaker2/ to create your own font file. It will generate a .ttf file that represents your custom font, with your time symbol.

Then after that, just import your ttf font file in your css style sheet and it should be okay.

Comment: In the future, try to add an example. If you have just a link in your answer and later the link is no good, the answer then is no good. I upvoted your answer because you have no rep yet, just keep it in mind in the future.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Noted. Thanks.

Comment: @Y_xD Thanks for this also. Would be very useful.

Comment: Sorry for the missing example, I'll keep it in mind in the future ;)